# How to align specific elements to the left inside a Column Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, alignment, padding

In the following code I'd like to align the name 'Jonny Bas' and '#coder' to leftmost

```
 body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
           child:Text(
              'Information',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
         SizedBox(height: 100),
          Text(
              'Praveen Kumar',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color:Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
              'Coding star- 4',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Align' widget or 'positioned' widget if you want to make change in only one or two widget but if want to give all of widgets the same alignment of parent widget column then you can use MainAxisAlignment and CrossAxisAlignment with specified attributes of left/right/etc...

Check the documentation links below for more info on how to use them,

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

"A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack" so it shouldn't be used in a column per op's example